# can we simplify following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation:

$x^2dy + y^2 dx = 0$

If we look at above equation it almost looks vague because it doesn't specify according to which independent variable are we getting the derivative of.

But, if we simplify this, it yields:

$dy/dx = -y^2/x^2$

after simplifying, it definitely seems an ODE because it deals with the derivative with respect to single independent variable.

Now I wanted to ask, can we simplify a given equation like I did to tell whether a given equation is ODE or not.

According to my understanding, it is:

1) Ordinary Differential Equation

2) Its order is 1

3) Its degree is 1

4) It is not a linear differential equation. (because the variables x and y have exponent of power 2)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also stay inside the formalism (probably of exact differential equations) and write
$$
0=y^2dx+x^2dy=x^2y^2\,d\left(-\frac1x-\frac1y\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, this is a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation, we can solve it this way:

$$x^2\space\text{d}x+y(x)^2\space\text{d}x=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2y'(x)+y(x)^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=-\frac{y(x)^2}{x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int-\frac{1}{x^2}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{1}{y(x)}=\frac{1}{x}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=-\frac{x}{\text{C}x+1}$$

If we know the right conditions, we can solve $\text{C}$, set $y(a)=b$:

$$b=-\frac{a}{\text{C}a+1}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=-\frac{a+b}{ab}$$